# Use angular material form field error messages on nested form elemets

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying figure out how to use Angular Material's Form Field error messages.

Typescript:

```
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
       personalInfo: this._formBuilder.group({
       email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
       password: ['', Validators.required],
       passwordConfirm: ['', Validators.required]
    });

     getErrorMessage() {
       return this.email.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
         this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' : '';
     }
```

HTML:

```
            <ng-container formGroupName="personalInfo">
               <ng-template matStepLabel class="tb_type-group__copy">Personal Info</ng-template>
               <div class="row column">
                  <div class="row">
                    <h4 class="tb_heading--h4">Account Info</h4>
                  </div>
               <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput class="tb_input" type="text" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" required>
                 <mat-error>{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field>
                <input #email matInput class="tb_input" type="password" placeholder=" Password"
                  formControlName="password" required>
                <mat-hint>Passwords must include 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number, and 1 special character. e.g.
                  P@ssw0rd</mat-hint>
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput class="tb_input" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password"
                  formControlName="passwordConfirm" required>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
```

I am attempting to use the material tutorial on how to use the form errors but I can not figure out how to access my elements. Their example is a single control element where my elements are nested in two groups. How can I go about getting this to work. If i just plug in their basic example the error message works so its not an angular material import issue or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already solved it yourself, but if not:
You can access the formGroup variable (in your code firstFormGroup), and use it's controls array to access the formField.

I prefer to use *ngIf to show/hide the messages here, it is better not to have a mat-error with an empty srting.

So, in the component, you can remove the getErrorMessage member, and solve the thing inside the html template:

```
     <mat-error *ngIf="firstFormGroup.controls['email']?.errors">
        {{ 
           firstFormGroup.controls['email'].hasError('required') 
           ? 'You must enter a value' 
           : (firstFormGroup.controls['email'].hasError('email')
              ? 'Not a valid email'
              : 'There is error with this email')
        }}
     </mat-error>
```

Note: Nowadays you can use typed forms, for extra safety.